# Почему не подключается js файл к typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js

Я создал конфигурацию для ts проекта через sequlize cli. Но почему-то models/models.js файл не подключается вот код app.ts

`import db from './models';`

Вот ошибка:

```
/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:587
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts:3:16 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './models'. '/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/src/models/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

3 import db from './models';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:587:12)
    at reportTSError (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:591:19)
    at getOutput (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:921:36)
    at Object.compile (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1189:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1295:42)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1298:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

вот config/config

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
  test: {
    username: 'root',
    password: null,
    database: 'database_test',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql',
  },
  production: {
    usernam: 'root',
    password: null,
    database: 'database_production',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql',
  },
};
```

вот model/index.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.ts');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Что не так?

Comment: tsconfig, `"compilerOptions": { "allowJs": true }`

Comment: @nörbörnën, ответы - в тответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy лучше закрыть дубликатом

Comment: @nörbörnën, да, тоже вариант.